# How can I get it to display the average as "Day(s) hr(s) min" format like the input before I average

Tags: mysql, time, average, days

I have a table "Results" that contains the field "TimeOpened" It is a varchar , The "TimeOpened" is a the sum of a Jscript of two fields from another table.

What I can't seem to get right is...  The format of "TimeOpen" is "3 Day(s) 1hr(s) 2 min 50 sec"  I am trying get the average of "TimeOpen".  Everything I have tried gives me a decimal like 47.34323434   where 47 is the days.   How can I get it to display the average as "Day(s) hr(s) min" format like the input before I average. (Example: Average time open is "47 Day(s) 2hr(s) 5 min 20 sec")  Here is the code.

```
SELECT `PropertyCode`,
       AVG(`TimeOpen`) AS `AVG(TimeOpen)`
FROM `Work_Order_Global`
```

Comment: You should do that type of transformation in the application, not the database.

Comment: Thank you  .  I will research it some more with PHP.   Any suggestions as how to approach this ?